# Run Alter Database with Set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run the SQL statement below:

```
 ALTER DATABASE DBNAME
 SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

However when I ran it does not complete the execution I have to terminate after an 1hr.

Is there any suggestion on how to run this without disconnecting all other user from the database?
Thanks

Comment: USE master
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 3):

Completion of this command requires, for just an instant, to be the only transaction open against the database. It seems to me that this *almost* requires that you put the DB into single-user mode briefly. But maybe if you just leave the query (trying to) run overnight, at some point you'll get that magic instant.

There's a bit more on the topic here: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Edit: the books online offers a bit more detail:

> When you set ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to a new state (from ON to OFF, or from OFF to ON), ALTER DATABASE does not return control to the caller until all existing transactions in the database are committed. If the database is already in the state specified in the ALTER DATABASE statement, control is returned to the caller immediately. If the ALTER DATABASE statement does not return quickly, use sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions to determine whether there are long-running transactions. If the ALTER DATABASE statement is canceled, the database remains in the state it was in when ALTER DATABASE was started. The sys.databases catalog view indicates the state of snapshot-isolation transactions in the database. If snapshot_isolation_state_desc = IN_TRANSITION_TO_ON, ALTER DATABASE ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF will pause six seconds and retry the operation.